# How do I use typedef with class initializer parameters in C++?

Tags: c++, types, macros, precompile

I'm asking this question like this because I don't know how to phrase it better.

Right now, I'm writing a 3D-Application using the Eigen library. Eigen only has a Vector class, but I need distinct vector and point data types.

Both can be represented by an

```
Eigen::Vector4d(x,y,z,w)
```

where w is 1 for a point and 0 for a vector.

I know that I can define a type by using

```
typedef vec3d Eigen::Vector4d
```

or

```
#define point3d Eigen::Vector4d
```

but is there a way to define it in a way so that w is always going to be 0 for a vector and 1 for a point?

```
typedef vec3d(x,y,z) Eigen::Vector4d(x,y,z,w)
```

doesn't work.

Comment: `#define point3d Eigen::Vector4d` please don't every write that again, it's very bad practice.

Comment: Yeah, I know, I wouldn't use it in C++, but it's at least a *possible* way of doing it.

Comment: Use a macro or a factory method for that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can inherit from it and provide a new constructor:

```
struct vec3d : Eigen::Vector4d {
    vec3d(double x, double y, double z) : Vector4d(x, y, z, 0) {}
};
```

Or, what I would prefer, is to write a factory function like:

```
Eigen::Vector4D make_vector(double x, double y, double z) {
    return {x, y, z, 0};
}
```